# Does echo in PHP starts printing on a new line? If no then why it's happening in my case?

Tags: php, string, echo, newline

I've following PHP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "<h2>PHP is Fun!</h2>";
echo "Hello world!<br>";
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not understanding why without adding `<br>` at the end of first echo statement the next echo statement printing the data on a new line?

The same is not happening in below example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "Jumbo";
echo "Hello world!<br>";
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the output as  `JumboHello world!`

Why so? I mean at one place echo takes new line charcter before start printing the text and at another place it's not.

Please clear the concept to me in detail manner.

Thanks.

Comment: its because of your `<h2>` html tag

Comment: Because anything after `<hX>` tags are automatically fed on a new line.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:You mean to say echo never adds a new line character before printing any string. This is happening in my case because I've used  <hX> am I getting you right?

Comment: `<body>

<?php` in HTML source, that will appear as a (new) blank line, if that's what the question is about. Plus, `echo "Jumbo";` PHP does not automatically insert a new line between it. You have to tell it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "new line" you are referring to visually when viewing the page in a browser.  In HTML you have block-level elements, which by default appear on their own line, and there are also line breaks, defined by `<br>`

`echo` does not add anything other than what you tell it to output.

`<h2>` is a block-level element by default, so in your first example, `Hello world!` will appear below it.

In your second example, you are outputting a `<br>` tag after the text, meaning the line break is after `Hello world`